# DataGridView open forms by row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a class People and i will save 3 or more people in class with list and i want to show it in a datagrid but when i double click in a row i want to open a form with the data of that people. i have this code:

```
    foreach (people P in RD.GetListPeople())
            {
                string type = cbType.SelectedItem.ToString();
                if (type == "Student")
                {
                    if (P is Student)
                    {
                        Student A = (Student)P;
                        FormStudent FA = new FormStudent(A);
                        FA.Show();
                    }
                }
                if (type == "Teacher")
                {
                    if (P is Teacher)
                    {
                        Teacher D = (_Teacher)P;
                        FormTeacher FD = new FormTeacher();
                        FD.Show();
                    }
                }
```

Teacher and Student are class or value from combobox "type".
I already can show all the persons on datagrid but i want something like (Show more...) and open new Form with all information about Person.
I use this code in dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick but this will open all form for each person i have and i want it to show just for the row i doubleclick. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

For starters you probably want to get rid of the `foreach` loop you have at the top - this is the reason you are seeing multiple forms pop up.
You only want to get the data of the row you have clicked on, so you will want to use `dataGridView1.SelectedRows` or `SelectedCells`.
Take a look at this question and see if it helps [Getting data from selected datagridview row and which event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260843/getting-data-from-selected-datagridview-row-and-which-event). If not you'll have to provide more information so we can understand your scenario better.