# How to Display Data from DataGridView to TextBox Without Select Button?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="width: 615px; margin: 30px;" class="table table-hover table-bordered" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndex2"></asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndex2(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    txtLastName.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[3].Text;
    txtFirstName.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
}
```

Based on above code, I generate data in the `GridView`, and supposedly, when I clicked one of the `rows` in `GridView`, the data will be displayed in each `textbox` based on the `cells` in each `rows`.

From what I looked up from the sources, I found the codes that use select button only. and I want to display data without select button.

So, somebody can help me?

Comment: You can use datagridview selection change event for this refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11293450/795683

Comment: but that one is using windows.forms. is it work for me?

Comment: Please refer this for gridview https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Selecting-GridView-Row-by-clicking-anywhere-on-the-Row.aspx

Comment: @SainPradeep I already followed what you gave me at the above comment. But, i still can't select the row. and also, one of the cells in the row GridView is missing.

Comment: can you please add your complete code for designer and code behind

Comment: Sorry, I did some silly mistakes. It is already corrected. Thank you @SainPradeep